# How do i write the contents of a variable into fs.writeFile

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, fs

I'm fairly new to Node.js and coding in general but I'm trying to 
write the value of the variable named parsed into `fs.writeFile()`

Is there any way to do it because whenever I run this it creates the txt file but it has `[object Object]`

My apologies in advance if this doesn't make any sense:

```
https.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zip},us&APPID=${config.key}`, res => {

    res.on('data', data => {
        body = data.toString();
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        const parseData = JSON.parse(body);
        fs.writeFile('data.txt', parsedData)
        console.log(parsed_data);
    });

});

module.exports = wrappedAll;
```

Comment: ` body = data.toString();` where body is declared? And you should use `body += data.toString();` (collect parts of data)

Comment: declare `body` first before you try to use it. and pass a string as second argument to `writeFile`. you are passing an object.

Comment: why do you need to use `JSON.parse`? If it is really needed for some other operation then trying using `JSON.stringify(parsedData)` in `writeFile`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[object Object]*** is the default conversion from an object to a string. Please be aware that in the following part of your code -

```
res.on('data', data => {
    body = data.toString();
});
```

You assign a different value to the ***body*** variable each time (overriding the previous value). What you want to do instead is to append to the ***body*** variable a new data chunk on every 'data' event.

It is crucial to understand that you don't get your data as a complete piece, you get it as a stream: on every 'on' event you get only part of it (and only on 'end' event you will have it as a whole) so it doesn't really make sense to parse it as a partially complete data piece.

You can parse your data when it finishes loading (on 'end' event), but, because you anyway write your response into a file, you can just leave your response as a string, you don't have or need to parse it anyway.

I suggest to do the following instead:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const url =
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=${zip},us&APPID=${config.key}";

function yourFunc(zip, config) {
  https.get(url, res => {
    let result = '';

    res.on('data', data => {
      result += data;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
      fs.writeFile('data.text', result);
    });
  });
}
```